# addProvider method in Security returns undefined

Tags: java, android

I am trying to use the `addProvider` method and seems it undefined even though it is imported  `import java.security.Security;`

```
package com.example.fingerprient2;
import java.security.KeyFactory;
import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.security.KeyPairGenerator;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.PrivateKey;

import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.Signature;

import java.security.Security;

import java.security.interfaces.ECPublicKey;

import java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException;
import java.security.spec.X509EncodedKeySpec;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.security.Security;
import org.bouncycastle.jcajce.BCFKSLoadStoreParameter;
import org.bouncycastle.jce.ECNamedCurveTable;
import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;
import org.bouncycastle.jce.spec.ECParameterSpec;
import android.security.keystore.KeyProperties;
import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator;

public class EnCryptor {



    Security.addProvider(new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider());
    KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(
            KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_EC, "AndroidKeyStore");
    KeyGenerator keyGenerator =KeyGenerator.getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_EC ,"AndroidKeyStore");

}
```

any help to know why addProvider doesn't appear?

Answer (score 0):

Because you're not in a scope where you can call a method. It needs to be called from a function or an initializer:

```
public class Encryptor {
    public void initialize() {
        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot, the problem has been solved. but I have another error in KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(
                KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES , "AndroidKeyStore");
the error is : Unhandled exceptions: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException, java.security.NoSuchProviderException